# Special price products custom page magento2

Tags: magento2, product, custom, special-price, page

How can I show products with **special price** (or discounted products) in a separate page in Magento 2 ?

Thanks.!

Comment: You can refer this - https://www.h-o.nl/blog/display_special_priced_products_on_your_magento_homepage

Comment: That is for magento1, i am in magento2

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it using the following:

```
$collection->addFinalPrice()
              ->addMinimalPrice()
              ->getSelect()
              ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');
```